# Showing a toast notification on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5. I am having trouble displaying a toast notification when I submit a form in MVC 5. It does not display on the page after I click submit. This is the code:

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactData formdata)
    {

        //what is supposed to happen when form is successful and there are no validation errors
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var data = new ContactData
            {
                FirstName = formdata.FirstName,
                LastName = formdata.LastName,
                Email = formdata.Email,
                Message = formdata.Message

            };

            //add the message to the messages table and then save the changes
            _dbContext.Messages.Add(data);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Success"] = "Success";
            return RedirectToAction("Contact","Home");
        }
        return View(formdata); //else re display the form showing the validation errors
    }
```

This is the JavaScript in the **View:**

```
@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if (TempData.ContainsKey("Success")) {
                toastr.success("Message Sent Successfully");
            }

        }

    </script>
}
```

Note: I have implemented the form using HTML helper methods rather than JQuery. This is my **form**:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <br /><br />
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary() <!--shows a list of the validation errors-->
        <div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <strong>Leave a Message:</strong>
            </div>

            <span class="clearfix"></span> <!--makes the content go to the left-->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left:4px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(t => t.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.FirstName, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left:4px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(t => t.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.LastName, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left:10px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left:10px;">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
            </div>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>


            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <input id="btnRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
            </div>

        </div>
    }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Is the redirect happening  to `/Contact`? Do you have the javascript code inside the `Contact` view ?

Comment: Yes the page redirects back to the Contact page (where the form is) and yes the JavaScript code is in the Contact view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `TempData` is server side code, So you should prefix it with `@`.

I like to render the script inside an if condition so that if `TempData.ContainsKey("Success")` returns `false`, the script will not be even rendered to the page (less script to compile and parse)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    @if(TempData.ContainsKey("Success"))
    {
        @:toastr.success("Message Sent Successfully");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that TempData is in your Controller, and would need to be handled in your View as a part of the Model, or, if you have access to to TempData in your view, you'd need to define it in a Razor block like this:

```
<script>
    var jsTempDataSuccess = '@TempData["Success"]';
</script>
```

And then in your document ready, you can do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (jsTempDataSuccess && jsTempDataSuccess == "Success") {
            toastr.success("Message Sent Successfully");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I also added a bracket as it was complaining of a syntax error.